# How to open dialog fragment in a fragment xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin

How do I open a dialog fragment in a fragment?

```
        private void Adapter_RateItemClick(object sender, DriversAdapterClickEventArgs e)
        {

// I wanted to open a dialog fragment in here how do I do this?
        }
```

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below link may be it will be helpful for you.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-dialog-fragment-using-xamarin-android/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could try this in your fragment:

```
private void Adapter_RateItemClick(object sender, DriversAdapterClickEventArgs e)
  {

     MyDialogFragment mdf = new MyDialogFragment();// this is your DialogFragment
     var ft = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
     mdf.Show(ft, "MyDialogFragment");
  }
```

Comment: it say's cannot convert from android.app.fragmenttrascation to android.support.v4.app.fragment manager

Comment: on which line ？

Comment: on the mdf.show(ft, "myDialogFragment"); the ft is the underlined problem

Comment: do you use `var ft = Activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();` above,mdf.Show have two kinds of parameters，one is `public virtual void Show(FragmentManager manager, string tag);` and another is   `public virtual int Show(FragmentTransaction transaction, string tag); `,you could check it